# spring dependency nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

Tags: xml, spring, dependency-injection

i am trying to learn spring and getting the above error

the main error is

```
Line 9 in XML document from class path resource [config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 75; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:402)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     ">
       
    <!-- Bean definition -->
    <bean class="com.springcore.student" name="student1">
        <!-- Setter injection -->
        <property name="studentId" value="01"/>
        <property name="studentName" value="Vinay"/>
        <property name="studentAdd" value="delhi"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKBqI.png)